# What's the difference between dot syntax and square bracket syntax?

Tags: objective-c

I am going through some walkthroughs fpr Objective-C and I got to many places where I raised my eyebrows. I would love to get them down.

1. Is there a fundamental difference in message sending and method calling? Objective-C lets me do both: `object.message` yields the same result as `[object message]`. I think maybe nested messages cannot be created using the dot operator strategy?
2. I created an `NSArray` object, now I am about to print results for this using an `NSEnumerator`:

   `id myObject = [object objectEnumerator];`

   in a while loop iterating and printing results. The *type* of `myObject` is `id`, which means it's resolved at runtime and not compile time. I know very clearly what kind of objects are stored in my `NSArray`—they are `NSString`s—so by changing the type of `myObject` to
   `NSString * myObject`, it works just fine. However, I experimented and found out that `myObject` can be of any type, be it `NSString` or `NSArray` or `NSEnumerator`, and any of these work just fine, perfectly iterating the `NSArray` object and yielding the same results.
   What's up with that?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure what kind of distinction you're trying to make between "message sending" and "method calling", since they're two ways of describing the same thing. The dot syntax is just a shortcut for calling getters and setters, that is:

```
[foo length]
foo.length
```

are exactly the same, as are:

```
[foo setLength:5]
foo.length = 5
```

You should generally only use the dot syntax when you're using getters and setters; use the square bracket syntax for all of your other method calls.

For your second question: this is how dynamic typing works. Any type declarations you put in your code are hints to the compiler; your Objective-C method calls will always work as long as the objects respond to them.

Comment: There's a small and usually irrelevant distinction, because the message that an object receives might not cause a method of the same name to be called.

Comment: "You should generally only use the dot syntax when you're using getters and setters; use the square bracket syntax for all of your other method calls." Why is that so?

Answer (score 9):

It's a distinction oriented at the person reading your code. Dot syntax indicates state (I'm accessing an ivar), method syntax indicates behavior (I'm performing some action). To the runtime, both are the same.

I think Apple's intention is to show accessors as an implementation detail you shouldn't worry about. Even when they could trigger side effects (due to some additional code in the accessor), they usually don't, so the abstraction is imperfect but worth it (IMHO). Another downside of using dot notation is that you don't really know if there is a struct or a union behind it (which unlike message sending, never trigger side effects when being assigned). Maybe Apple should have used something different from a dot. `*shrugs*`

> I think maybe nested messages cannot be created using the dot operator strategy?

Dot notation can be used to nest calls, but consider the following:

```
shu.phyl.we.spaj.da
[[[[[shu]phyl]we]spaj]da]
```

In this case, the uglier, the better. Both are a code smell because one object is creating dependencies to another object far far away, but if use brackets to pass messages you get that extra horrible syntax from the second line, which makes the code smell easier to notice. Again, convention is to use dots for properties and brackets for methods.

Comment: +1 for the "In this case, the uglier, the better." in a context in which it actually makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

1: Your terminology is incorrect. The dot operator is not "method calling", a different operation. It's just a different visual appearance for message sending. There's no difference between [x y] and x.y. The dot syntax can only take one argument though, as it's intended to be used only for property access.

2: The static (compile-time) type of an object has no effect on its behavior at runtime. Your object is still an NSEnumerator even if you're calling it something else.

Comment: Dot notation can me used for getters and setters.  [object setValue: 5] is the same as object.value = 5.  You're right that using it for anything that getters and setters is asking for trouble.

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have clarified that rather than just the blanket no arguments description. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

1)  They're both message sending, just different syntax.  [object message] is traditional syntax, object.message is the "dot notation", but means exactly the same thing.  You can do some kinds of nesting with dot notation, but you can't do anything with methods that take complex arguments.  In general, old hand Obj-C programmers don't use dot notation except for simple accessor calls.  IMHO.

2)  The runtime is really smart and can figure it out on the fly.  The type casting of pointers is really just a clue to the compiler to let you know when you messed up.  It doesn't mean a thing (in this case) when the message is sent to the array to fetch a value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Message sending is the preferred way of doing this. It's what the community uses and reinforces the concept of objects sending messages to one another which comes into play later when you get into working with selectors and asking an object if it responds to a selector (message).
2. `id` is basically a pointer to anything. It takes some getting used to but it's the basis for how Objective-C handles dynamic typing of objects. When `NSLog()` comes across the `%@` format specifier, it sends a `description` message to the object that should should replace the token (This is implemented in the superclass `NSObject` and can be overridden in the subclass to get the desired output).

In the future when you're doing this, you might find it easier to do something like this instead:

```
for (NSString *s in YourNSArrayInstance) //assuming they are NSStrings as you described
{
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

Or even simply just:

```
for (NSString *s in YourNSArrayInstance) //assuming they are NSStrings as you described
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

You'll learn to like message sending eventually.