# iOS - Calling [UIColor redColor] vs UIColor.redColor

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS / Objective-C, I am wondering what the difference between calling certain class constants in the 2 different ways possible.

Basically, what is the difference between `[UIColor redColor]` and `UIColor.redColor`? I see nearly all tutorials write it with the brackets but from my tests, there doesn't seam to be any difference. This works for many other similar situations such as:

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter`, `Object.class`, etc. Is there any reason to use the brackets or can I keep a standard and use the dot (.)?

Also, how would you define a class variable like that? If I have a class called `BestClass` how could I make a variable such as `BestClass.coolColor` which would return a UIColor (the same way calling `UIColor.redColor` returns a UIColor object)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dot syntax and square bracket syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423853/whats-the-difference-between-dot-syntax-and-square-bracket-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot syntax is used to call the setter/getter methods of properties (defined with the `@property` statement) and given properties are defined at the instance-level, not class-level, the form `[ClassName methodName]` is better.

However it's just syntactic sugar, so both will work.

Class methods are defined using `+`:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ (int)aClassMethod;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same.
The default way for you to call accessor methods of a property is the bracket notation, the dot notation here is just a short way to do the same.

From the Obj-C programming guide:

> Dot syntax is purely a convenient wrapper around accessor method
> calls. When you use dot syntax, the property is still accessed or
> changed using the getter and setter methods mentioned above:
>
> Getting a value using somePerson.firstName is the same as using
> [somePerson firstName]
>
> Setting a value using somePerson.firstName =
> @"Johnny" is the same as using [somePerson setFirstName:@"Johnny"]